# About iBatis mapped parameters

Tags: ibatis

when i have a query for ibatis like this

```
<insert id="createSomething" parameterClass="com.abc.something.CreateSomething">
INSERT INTO ABC (
                MASTER_ID
                ) 
         VALUES ( 
                 #masterId:NUMERIC:-1#
                )
 </insert>
```

with pojo CreateSomething having int masterId = -1 with getter and setter.

what is the meaning of `#masterId:NUMERIC:-1#`, here i can understand masterId is of NUMERIC type but what is the associated -1 use here, and what will be the equivalent Mybatis query be.